# What is the big difference if exists between java and javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I've read a lot about java. And I couldn't understand what is the big difference between java and JavaFX is it just an extension of Java. Or is it actual native library. And what use does it have. 
As I've read JavaFX as the name says is good with effects and multimedia. But is it not possible to do that without JavaFX?

Comment: java == programming language. javaFX == classes you can use inside java. Can you make graphical things without javaFX? Sure. It all depends on what you need though. JavaFX lets you style things with CSS if that's what you need or like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java (as you probably already know) is a programming language.
JavaFX is a Java library for creating graphical user interfaces intended to run across multiple platforms, and is included in the Java platform. Programs that use the JavaFX toolkit are written in Java. It formerly included its own language (JavaFX Script) that compiled to Java bytecode, but this was dropped in version 2.0 of JavaFX.

To answer your comment, JavaFX includes **both Java code and native code in C, C++, Objective-C, and Objective-C++**. In fact, there are more native code files (including headers) than Java files. This was found by downloading the source [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt) and searching for files with various extensions, using the following commands.

```
$ find | grep -P "\.java$" | wc -l
5907
$ find | grep -P "\.(c|h|cpp|cc|hpp|m|mm)$" | wc -l
8518
```

Comment: Does it include native code like java or is it based on the Java library?